# Trying to install my own package as per polls app tutorial based on django

Tags: python, django

So I finished my tutorial on polls app and now i'm in the Advance tutorial "How to make reusable app." I was successful in making my own package. Now comes the installing the package part. I tried this command:

```
pip install --user django-polls/dist/django-polls-0.1.tar.gz
```

and i'm getting this error:

```
Can not perform a '--user' install. User site-packages are not visible in this virtualenv.
```

What should i do now? Any suggestions?

NOTE: I'm using virtual environment

Answer (score 1):

Since you have activated the virtual env, I would remove the `--user` flag, and the package will be installed in your virtual env.

```
pip install django-polls/dist/django-polls-0.1.tar.gz
```

Comment: i removed --user flag as you suggested. Now it's showing Requirement 'django-student/dist/django-student-0.1.tar.gz' looks like a filename, but the file does not exist
 this. Is it because of virtualenv?

Comment: That's a separate issue. You'd get that error the file does not exist at that location.

Comment: i checked in dist directory. the file is there.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you won't get that error if you use the correct location. Double check the current directory you are in and make sure that the `django-student/dist` part is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are in the same directory as `django-polls/dist/django-polls-0.1.tar.gz` before you run `pip install django-polls/dist/django-polls-0.1.tar.gz`